# IBM Cloud-Watson NLC - TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'iam_apikey'

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, nl-classifier

I am currently trying to deploy an application from a repo. (https://github.com/IBM/nlc-icd10-classifier#run-locally) But it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 34, in <module>
    iam_apikey=nlc_iam_apikey
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'iam_apikey'
```

I am on Python 3.6.8

app.py:

```
load_dotenv(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), ".env"))

nlc_username = os.environ.get("NATURAL_LANGUAGE_CLASSIFIER_USERNAME")
nlc_password = os.environ.get("NATURAL_LANGUAGE_CLASSIFIER_PASSWORD")
nlc_iam_apikey = os.environ.get("NATURAL_LANGUAGE_CLASSIFIER_IAM_APIKEY")
classifier_id = os.environ.get("CLASSIFIER_ID")

# Use provided credentials from environment or pull from IBM Cloud VCAP
if nlc_iam_apikey != "placeholder":
    NLC_SERVICE = NaturalLanguageClassifierV1(
      iam_apikey=nlc_iam_apikey
    )
elif nlc_username != "placeholder":
    NLC_SERVICE = NaturalLanguageClassifierV1(
      username=nlc_username,
      password=nlc_password
```

.env:

```
CLASSIFIER_ID=<add_NLC_classifier_id>
#NATURAL_LANGUAGE_CLASSIFIER_USERNAME=<add_NLC_username>
#NATURAL_LANGUAGE_CLASSIFIER_PASSWORD=<add_NLC_password>

NATURAL_LANGUAGE_CLASSIFIER_IAM_APIKEY="placeholderapikeyforstackoverflolw"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you ran into an issue with the Watson SDK. Recently, with V4, they introduced a [breaking change](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk/blob/master/MIGRATION-V4.md) which I found in their [release notes](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk/releases). There is a new, more abstract authentication mechanism that caters to different authentication types. You would need to slightly change the code for how NLC is initialized.

This is from the [migration instructions](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk/blob/master/MIGRATION-V4.md):

> For example, to pass a IAM apikey:

**Before**

```
from ibm_watson import MyService

service = MyService(
    iam_apikey='{apikey}',
    url='{url}'
)
```

**After(V4.0)**

```
from ibm_watson import MyService
from ibm_cloud_sdk_core.authenticators import IAMAuthenticator

authenticator = IAMAuthenticator('{apikey}')
service = MyService(
    authenticator=authenticator
)
service.set_service_url('{url}')
```