# Python Ibm_watson: ImportError: cannot import name 'MyService'

Tags: python, python-3.x, ibm-watson

I am trying to use IBM_Watson tone analyser in Python program. I was following this thread ([IBM Cloud-Watson NLC - TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'iam_apikey'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58909463/ibm-cloud-watson-nlc-typeerror-init-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument)) to initiate the instance of IBM_Watson in the Python program. When I run the command `from ibm_watson import MyService`, it throws an error message of `ImportError: cannot import name 'MyService'`. Version 4.3.0 of Ibm_watson is installed on my machine. Has anyone came across the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

This will be because you have the name of the service in the import wrong. Maybe a s for z typo, or a missing V3.

Based on the API Python SDK for the Tone Analysis - https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/tone-analyzer?code=python

```py
from ibm_watson import ToneAnalyzerV3
from ibm_cloud_sdk_core.authenticators import IAMAuthenticator

authenticator = IAMAuthenticator('{apikey}')
tone_analyzer = ToneAnalyzerV3(
    version='{version}',
    authenticator=authenticator
)

tone_analyzer.set_service_url('{url}')
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to `import ToneAnalyzerV3` from `ibm_watson` using the code:

```
from ibm_watson import ToneAnalyzerV3
from ibm_cloud_sdk_core.authenticators import IAMAuthenticator
```

But its showing:

```
"ImportError: cannot import name 'ToneAnalyzerV3' from 'ibm_watson' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ibm_watson/__init__.py)"
```

While I was installing `ibm_watson` library there was also another `error`

```
"ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
 google-colab 1.0.0 requires requests~=2.23.0, but you have requests 2.27.1 which is incompatible.
 datascience 0.10.6 requires folium==0.2.1, but you have folium 0.8.3 which is incompatible"
```

But when I rerun the cell containing the code

```
!pip install ibm_watson
```

it was gone. If anyone knows to solve this kindly reply soon.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please post this as a new question

Answer (score -1):

Not completely sure but based on what you've said, it seems like you don't have an API key which is needed for Watson. An API key basically just shows you have the rights to the program. To get an API key, make an IBM Watson account and go to the part of Watson that you're using. Then you can generate an API key and put it into your program where you need to. Hope this helps!!

Comment: I already have API Key. This step come before initialising of API key. It does not link with API key